# How can I restrict a certain user to one table in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

My database is a standard MySQL database provided to me by my web hosting company.

I have tried to issue this GRANT command that grants SELECT, INSERT, and UPDATE privileges to the specified user on the specific table.

```
GRANT select, insert, update ON database.table TO RestrictedUser
```

For some reason, this is kicking back this error.

```
#1142 - GRANT command denied to user 'adminuser'@'localhost' for table 'tablename'
```

I am using PHPMyAdmin that my hosting company provides so I should have full admin privs correct?

Note- I've edited out the actual table names for security purposes.

Comment: `adminuser` doesn't appear to have `GRANT` privileges. You should have a user on shared hosting with appropriate privileges to set something like this up. Your statement will look something like this: `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON db.table TO '<user>'@'<host>'`

Comment: Then, which account will give me grant privileges? I'm using the account that is built in the web hosting company's instance of PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: If you have cPanel or something like that, you might want to go to MySQL from there and create a brand new user with all rights...and use it sparingly for situations like these.

Comment: I have a user created specifically for that purpose. When I use the hosting company's instance of PHPMyAdmin, it doesn't give me an option to login as any specific user. I click the button, and it opens up MyAdmin for me.

Comment: In PHPMyAdmin, top left side it might read PHPMyAdmin. Under it might be some icons. One might be query window. Click on it. Type `select current_user` and click Go. Remember the output. Go back to the query window and type `show grant`. One grant on the database of your interest must show `grant all privileges to db.* to <your username from select current_user`. Is that the case or not?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have GRANT privilege if you're working in a shared multitenant MySQL database.  Your next move is to open a support ticket with your hosting company asking them how to do what you're trying to do.

Don't be too surprised if they say, "we don't allow that."  Running large-scale multitenant MySQL instances is a risky business, and restricting the privileges of user accounts is one way hosting companies, especially the inexpensive ones, mitigate that risk.

Comment: This makes sense. I was getting ready to suggest that I open up a support ticket so I guess I will do that now. Thanks!